# ModelState is not valid due to validation on a nullable number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have in Model the property called "ID" of type "int?". And in View

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ID)
```

If Model.ID is null, the hidden field will have the value an empty string and on postback, ModelState.IsValid returns false because of the error:

```
"Object of type 'System.String' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]'."
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We do this every day in our solution and it's not an issue at all. Here is one of our models just as an example:

```
public class ClassifiedAd : BaseModel
{
    [Key]
    [Editable(false)]
    public int? ClassifiedAdID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    public int? UserID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    public int? ClassifiedAdCategoryID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [StringLength(15, ErrorMessage = "Limited to 15 characters!")]
    [RegularExpression(RegularExpressions.USPhone, ErrorMessage = "Must be a valid phone number!")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required!")]
    [RegularExpression(RegularExpressions.SafeAlphaNumeric, ErrorMessage = "Only letters, numbers, dashes and underscores are allowed!")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Limited to 100 characters!")]
    public string AddTitle { get; set; }
}
```

as you can see we use nullable types for all our model properties. This however does not cause any issues that you describe. In our views we have:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ClassifiedAdID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserID)
```

and everything maps and works fine. I'm not sure what causes your problem (need to see your entire code to figure that out) but I think you need to look at other possibilities here. What version of MVC are you using?

Comment: you are right, probably my update was not available by the time of your response, it was something already existing the project that caused this behavior (see my answer), it took me lots of time until I figure it out, but you are 100% right. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in your view:

```
var id = Model.ID.HasValue ? Model.ID.Value : false;
@Html.HiddenFor(m=> id)
```

Comment: can you please review the syntax? I believe something is not correct and I don't understand how it should act

Comment: Sorry, please try the above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that MVC apparently uses the same template for `Html.HiddenFor()` for a nullable int (`int?`) value as it does for a normal `int`. One pretty simple solution would be to only emit the hidden field in cases where the value is non-null:

```
@if ( Model.NullableInt.HasValue ) {
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.NullableInt);
}
```

In the case where `Model.NullableInt` is null, the hidden field won't be emitted, and thus you won't have the problem of an empty string showing up when you try to validate.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this in not the common behavior, I was extending in the project the DefaultModelBinder such that null values are being converted to empty strings and that's what was causing the error.